# Composite Primary Key XOR reference of 3 tables

Tags: mysql, primary-key

There is a table **calendar** which can be related both to companies **or** accountants. One row in **calendar** belongs exclusively (XOR) to an accountant **OR** to a comapny.

I create a Composite PK on calendar (snapshot 2) to reference either table, but not both at the same time. (one calendar entry **exclusively** belongs to an accountant **or** to a company):

Snapshot1:

[image: snapshot 1]

Snapshot2:

[image: snapshot 2]

My question is, how do I do this properly so I keep the referencial integrity?

```
calendar --> accountants
calendar --> companies
```

Comment: As far as I know there are no constraints available in MySQL to enforce that only companies xor accountants is referenced. However, you could use BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE triggers to intercept values that could violate the constraint, and modify them, perhaps setting both references to null, or favoring one over the other.

Comment: I guess, as you said, triggers will be the only way to ensure integrity in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there are no constraints available in MySQL to enforce that only companies xor accountants is referenced.

However, you could use BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE triggers to intercept values that could violate the constraint, and modify them; perhaps setting both references to null, favoring one over the other, setting some "attention required, bad entry" field, etc...